# Count number of records in API

Tags: counter, record

I'm making an application on the API [SWAPI](https://swapi.dev/api/starships/?page=1), this request lists all the star wars spaceships, I need to know how many there are of each of them, for example "CR90 corvette" has only 2, the problem is that it doesn't I see that data anywhere, is it possible what I want to do?

I tried looking for a counter record but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, did you perhaps overlook this search function;
https://swapi.dev/documentation#search

```
https://swapi.dev/api/starships/?search=corvette&format=json
```

```json
{
  "count": 1,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "CR90 corvette",
      "model": "CR90 corvette",
      "manufacturer": "Corellian Engineering Corporation",
      "cost_in_credits": "3500000",
      "length": "150",
      "max_atmosphering_speed": "950",
      "crew": "30-165",
      "passengers": "600",
      "cargo_capacity": "3000000",
      "consumables": "1 year",
      "hyperdrive_rating": "2.0",
      "MGLT": "60",
      "starship_class": "corvette",
      "pilots": [],
      "films": [
        "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
        "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/",
        "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
      ],
      "created": "2014-12-10T14:20:33.369000Z",
      "edited": "2014-12-20T21:23:49.867000Z",
      "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/2/"
    }
  ]
}
```